# LibGDX - how to make sizeToAction relative to other corner than bottom-left?

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to resize a widget inside a `Table`.
It's a fullscreen widget and when Android Keyboard comes out, the widget is resized so it fits half of the screen from the top.

SizeByAction works from the left-bottom corner so it resizes the widget down, and I have to resize it up.

For now I use a hack with a `parallel action` and I change it's `size` and `POSITION` in the same time so it looks like a want (like it was staying in the left-top corner all the time).

I know there's a originX and originY but they're used to rotation, not resizing elements.

If someone did something like this before without a hack  like mine, I would be grateful for a tip! :)

**How does the widget look like?** It's a fullscreen widget:
[image]

**How does it look after resize?**
[image]

**How I want it to look like?** 
I want it to rezise relative to it's left-up corner
[image]

Comment: So just to clarify, did you actually try setting the origin? Origin is used for scaling and rotating.

Comment: Tried. I don't use ScaleToAction cause it doesn't take values, it takes a scale and I need to hardcode a final value ;( ScaleByAction takes amounts, but it's risky to use cause it can resize elements to < 0

Comment: That's weird because `SizeToAction` actually calls `Actor.setSize`, which I assume should account for the origin. Have you triple-checked that you set the origin correctly? Actually, seems like this is the intended behaviour: `setSize` does not account for the origin, see [this thread](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/3272).

Comment: As written here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079531/actor-origin-in-scene-2d

setSize() works only for Scaling and Rotating ;(

Comment: That's why I made a hack, but the hack is making huge issues. Oh this GDX...

Comment: Thought about writing your own action that handles all this for you? The code in `SizeToAction` isn't very complicated and I'd imagine it can be modified to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I'll do something like that. It won't work in my case, cause there's a bigger problem - widget is also a Cell and I can't change it's position (cell position) which breaks everything later, for ex. if I add a new element to the widget, it goes back to it's 0,0 after invalidate(), but I'll figure something out. GDX lack features. Post this as an answer, I'll accept when noone comes with a better solution ;)